# Set android alarm in UTC

Tags: android, date, datetime, java-calendar

I'm using an API to fetch movie releases for my Android app and the release dates are in milliseconds UTC. When I take that release date and set it on the user's phone it gets converted in his time zone and called.

**Example:**

A movie's release date in milliseconds:

> 1509667200000

To UTC time & date:

> Fri Nov 03 2017 00:00:00

To local time & date: (Eastern time, my timezone)

> Thu Nov 02 2017 20:00:00

When I set my alarm

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(releaseDate);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), alarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did and now it works perfectly:

```
    // Calendar
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(releaseDate);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), alarmIntent);
```